# What is the best datatype for saving array of numbers in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am designing a database for saving the posts written by users. The posts have their id numbers and all i have to do is to save the ids of posts written by user x in x`s db. I am thinking that i should save them as strings like 11/1234/1452 by using varchar datatype but suddenly it feels a little bit of waste since i am using no alphabets and the char datatype is so costly. Is there a good way to save an array of numbers efficiently in mysql?

Comment: There are ways to do this, but your model will be denormalized. You will benefit from creating a `posts` table which will store `user_id` and insert new rows for every post rather than keeping ids in array. Performance boost would be very beneficial.

Comment: @consider me You mean it`s better to use select in tables of posts rather than selecting the user and then searching the posts by selecting primary key?

Comment: See @GordonLinoff answer. This is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The best data structure is a junction table, with one row per user and one per post.  It might look something like this:

```
create table UserPosts (
    UserPostId int primary key auto_increment,
    UserId int not null,
    PostId int not null,
    constraint fk_UserId foreign key (UserId) references Users(UserId),
    constraint fk_PostId foreign key (PostId) references Posts(PostId)
)
```

Alternatively, you might have a 1-N relationship and simply need a `Posts` table with a column for the `UserId` that saved it.

Comment: That first part, the ”junction“ or ”bridge“ table is for resolving a many-to-many relationship. That would mean a post can have more than one author, and an author can write more than one post. If a post can have only a single author, not plural, then you need two tables `user_` and `post_` where `post_` has a column (foreign key) that holds the author’s identifier (a copy of the primary key value from the `user_` table. That is how we represent a One-to-Many relationship.

Comment: @basil bourque Ive come to ask about this.... I think it would be a bad idea to have the users` key in the post table since it has lots of information included... since the table is so heavy it might take a long time to search for the specific post written by the author?

Comment: Both primary key and foreign key are always [indexed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) to help with that performance issue.

Comment: By the way, [relational database design](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design) is not a matter of opinion and preference. It is the only true "software engineering" in that it is defined precisely and proven with mathematics. Lookup Drs. [E.F. Codd](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd) and [Chris Date](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) to learn more.